# Console based speech program that can be run via SSH on Windows 7

Tags: cygwin, openssh, text-to-speech

I have just installed Cygwin with OpenSSH on my computer, and would like to have a speech program that I can run from a SSH session in a console, similar to the `say` command in Mac OS X.

I have tried [this](http://krolik.net/post/Say-exe-a-simple-command-line-text-to-speech-program-for-Windows.aspx) one but whenever I try to run it in an SSH session on my iPhone, i get the message `This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.`

I am using the app called 'SSH Terminal', if it is possible that it is the app that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to have a loop running on the computer that keeps checking for the existence of `say.txt` and if it exists, then say it and then delete the file. I then just put what I wanted to say in say.txt from my iPhone.

sayloop.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
if [ -f say.txt ]; then
    say `cat say.txt`
    rm -f say.txt
    sleep 1
fi
done
```

In an SSH session:

```
echo "say this" > say.txt
```